# Why doesn't inserting of json array to sql work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an HTML table, that stores its data into Javascript array, then stores into json array, and then I send it to php file. My problem is that I can't insert this json array into sql database. I have files: index.php (HTML is there), database.php, main.js, jquery.js, jquery.json.php and css.

```js
 var TableData;
    TableData = storeTblValues()
    TableData = $.toJSON(TableData);
    function storeTblValues()
    {
        var TableData = new Array();
    
        $('#table1 tr').each(function(row, tr){
            TableData[row]={
                "Id" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
                , "Name" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
            }
        });
        return TableData;
    }
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "database.php",
       data: "pTableData=" + TableData,
       success: function(msg){
           console.log('',15); //this shows in console when I load my HTML-file
       }
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
      <tr id="tr1">
        <td id="tdd1">1</td>
        <td id="td1">Add the name</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

PHP-code:

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="project";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
$tableData = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);
foreach($tableData as $item) {
       $sql='INSERT INTO projects (Id, Name)
       VALUES ('.$item['Id'].', '.$item['Name'].')';

     }
?>
```

It doesn't send me an error, just doesn't work.

Comment: You don't execute any queries.

Comment: did you get any errors??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending anything to database. You are just assigning value to variable.
To send query to database you need to use `mysqli_query()` function. Documentation can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
Change it so your SQL is send to database:

```
foreach($tableData as $item) {
  $sql='INSERT INTO projects (Id, Name)
  VALUES ('.$item['Id'].', \''.$item['Name'].'\')';
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

On the other hand I suggest you to not send all queries one by one but create one string which will send all values in one query. It can be done this way:

```
// Start of SQL
$sql = 'INSERT INTO projects(Id, Name) VALUES ';

// Loop to get all values
foreach($tableData as $item) {
  $sql .= '('.$item['Id'].', \''.$item['Name'].'\'),';
}

// Remove last comma
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');

// Send SQL to database
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

PS: You are missing commas when inserting string value to database.

Comment: When teaching someone how to use mysqli_query, please show how to use prepared statements too (and why they are important) ;) +1 anyway